# Postgresql: Show only the max value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

i have the following query that returns me the move, name of a container and the cicle of the container. The max value of the cicle on the container means that is the actual cicle of the same.

```
select     des.movimiento, 
           des.equipo_identi, 
           max(des.ciclo) as ciclo
from       publico.descarga des
inner join publico.prioridad_movimiento primo 
on         des.movimiento = primo.movimiento
group by   des.movimiento, des.equipo_identi, primo.prioridad
order by   primo.prioridad
```

It returns me this

```
 movimiento    | equipo_identi | ciclo
--------------- --------------- --------
Descarga       | CBHU4329906   | 1 
Descarga       | CSLU1387094   | 2 
Descarga       | CSLU1407729   | 2 
GateOut Puerto | CBHU4329906   | 1 
GateOut Puerto | CSLU1387094   | 2 
GateOut Puerto | CSLU1407729   | 2 
GateIn Patio   | CBHU4329906   | 1 
GateIn Patio   | CSLU1387094   | 2 
GateIn Patio   | CSLU1407729   | 2
```

---

What i want to is to show the last cicle(**ciclo**) on the last movement(**movimiento**) it has. Like this, shows these 3 different containers(**table title: equipo_identi**) that the last movement was "GateIn Patio":

```
  movimiento | equipo_identi | ciclo
------------- --------------- --------
GateIn Patio | CBHU4329906   | 1
GateIn Patio | CSLU1387094   | 2 
GateIn Patio | CSLU1407729   | 2
```

---

For this, i have the following table that set my movement priority.

### **Table prioridad_movimiento**

```
prioridad | movimiento
---------- ----------------
1         | Descarga
2         | GateOut Puerto
3         | GateIn Patio
4         | GateOut Patio
5         | GateIn Puerto
6         | Export
```

The max priority is 6 and the min is 1.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more the logic of the requirement? Why do you want to get all rows where movimiento = 'GateIn Patio'?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Because i need to see only the last cicle of the last movement it has the container, the movements can be any of the 6 listed.

Comment: I am not sure I understand; if you only need to see the last cycle of the last movement why do you expect all three rows of the last movement and not only one? [And this is only one of the things I don't understand]

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Because, each one of these three rows shows the last movement of a different container. That's because it shows 3, that means there are 3 containers that has the actual movement "GateIn Patio".

Comment: So the container is `equipo_identi`?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Yeah, i updated the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138768/discussion-between-giorgos-altanis-and-jorge).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to rank the results by priority after the aggregation:

```
select x.*
from (select des.movimiento, des.equipo_identi, max(des.ciclo) as ciclo,
             rank() over (order by primo.prioridad desc) as rnk
      from publico.descarga des inner join
           publico.prioridad_movimiento primo 
           on des.movimiento = primo.movimiento
      group by des.movimiento, des.equipo_identi, primo.prioridad
     ) x
where rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, i have tested your query, at first impression it looks like that is exactly what i want. I'm gonna add more data info for test this. By now, it's the correct answer.

Comment: Got an extra question, any tip for how to ignore a value according to a varchar and bigint(aggregation max) field?

Comment: @Jorge . . . I don't understand your question.  Questions should be asked as *new* questions, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation.